# EC2 Ubuntu with WordPress can't connect to RDS

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-12.04, amazon-rds

I have set up a WordPress website on a Ubuntu 12.04 Amazon ec2 machine by following [this tutorial](http://www.wpwebhost.com/install-wordpress-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts-localhost-lampp-server/) except the fact that I haven't created a MySQL database and I am using an amazon RDS MySQL service.

Everything works fine and I am able to create a configuration file during installation but when the installer asks for MySQL credentials. When I fill in the RDS credentials they don't work. 
I even tried entering the credentials manually in the `wp-confiq` file and still it said it couldn't connect to the database .

I tried to test out the same credentials on another WordPress installation in a shared hosting environment and the result was the same.

Then on the ec2 WordPress server I installed MySQL and then provided the MySQL details during installation and everything worked fine hence proving its something to do with RDS only.

Additional Details:

1. The DB security Group has only one security: the EC2 Security Group
2. Both EC2 and RDS are located in AWS singapore southeast-1a regions
3. EC2 Security: only port 22 (`ssh`) and 80 (`http`) opened

Comment: Can you paste the output of the following command:

`telnet <end-point> 3306` from your EC2 instance.

Comment: Also, result for this command from your ec2 instance .. `# host <mysql_end_point>`

Comment: i was using AWS singapore region and due to some internal network problems i couldnt connect to RDS and even on using the correct key pair i was not getting permission to log into ec2 instance .

As a result i couldnt use your requested commands (Sorry About That)
 So i tried using the AWS Virginia region and everything went great . I followed exact same steps as i did in singapre region so i sum it up to be a internal network problem within AWS singapore and hence you should avoid AWS singapore for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you can connect to the instance with the command line. See instructions here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html

Maybe you have a problem with the credentials or with the network. Once you find the root cause it is easier to solve it.

Comment: i was using AWS singapore region and due to some internal network problems i couldnt connect to RDS and even on using the correct key pair i was not getting permission to log into ec2 instance . So i tried using the AWS Virginia region and everything went great . I followed exact same steps as i did in singapre region so i sum it up to be a internal network problem within AWS singapore.

Thank You for your Answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shot in the dark. When you see your endpoint it will resolve to a different IP if you do it on your home/work DNS resolver as apposed to an AWS resolver. AWS will give you back a private IP which is valid to connect to.

So I'm thinking you are using custom nameserver's in /etc/resolv.conf and not amazon's. So you are getting back the public IP on your instance and it can't go out and back in the NAT.

Comment: Thank You for the response but i am not that good in linux so most of what you said got over my head . Can you please elaborate it a little in noob language?

Are you saying that changing to amazon nameservers in resolv.conf can be the solution?

P.S. with the help of google search related to your answer i could figure out that rds problem that i am facing can be because of some dns settings in resolv.conf but other than that i dont know what to change and how to change it